# Adaptar Formulario WindowsForms a pantalla, C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, aplicación-escritorio

Antes que todo **NO** estoy hablando de hacer el formulario `WindowsForms`a modo `responsive`. Mi formulario principal esta diseñado con una resolución de `1340` x `760` con estas propiedades establecidas de la siguiente forma:

- FormBorderStyle = FixedSingle.
- StartPosition = CenterScreen.
- WindowState = Maximized.

La laptop tiene una resolución de `1366` x `768`.

Aunque el formulario se posiciona mostrando la `Barra de tareas`, el formulario no cambia de tamaño según la resolución de pantalla y **la parte inferior de mi formulario se oculta o corta**.

> Mi formulario contiene dos paneles una lateral y otro que completa el tamaño del formulario. He creado esta función para adaptar el formulario al área de trabajo de la pantalla:

```
public void adaptarFormulario(Form formulario)
{
     formulario.Location = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Location;
     formulario.Size = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size;
}
```

En el `FormLoad`:

```
adaptarFormulario(this);
```

El Formulario se muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Para mostrarle la parte que esta ocultando he movido la `Barra de Tareas` a la parte Lateral Derecha de la pantalla.

No se muestra completo, esta **Cortando/Ocultando** esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Cómo puedo resolver este problema?**

**Entorno:** Visual Studio 2010 C#, & .NET NetFramework 4.

Comment: Aunque el formulario se posiciona mostrando la Barra de tareas, el formulario no cambia de tamaño según la resolución de pantalla y la parte inferior de mi formulario se oculta o corta.... no entiendo esta frase.. como que no cambia cuando cambias la resolucion de pantalla?

Comment: No, en ningún momento cambio la resolución de pantalla de la lapto, lo que digo es que el formulario no se muestra completo en la pantalla, esta ocultado la parte inferior, esta actuando como si la barra de tareas no existiera.

Comment: Trata de hacer un [mcve]. en realidad cuando le pones maximizar, ya deberia ocupar todo el espacio visible. Salvo, que su tamaño minimo sea mayor a tu resolucion, En ese caso se va a ir de largo.

Comment: No hay que hacer un ejmplo para esto, la pantalla por defecto sale **Maximizada** eso lo especifico en la descripción del problema, tiene esa propiedad establecida. y también he puesto ambas resoluciones la del diseño del formulario (es menor que la resolución de la pantalla)

Comment: si, pero esos 8 pixeles, son mucho menos que lo que ocupa la barra de tareas.. tu min, no es el minimo visible en la pantalla...

Comment: Entonces la Solución es: **Reducir el tamaño del formulario** ?

Comment: En general un programa se hace basado en la minima resolucion que puedas. No se puede asegurar que todos los usuarios del mismo van a tener semejante resolucion, porque si su pantalla es mas chica, no lo van a ver. Si, hay que reducir el tamaño.

Comment: Comprendo que debe hacerse a la mínima resolución posible,y si esta es la mínima que puedo tener? , me costará rediseñar tanto el formulario principal, como algunos otros formularios que se abriran dentro de este principal, los cuales puede llegar a tener un tamaño que sobre pase este límite. :(

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73578/discussion-between-gbianchi-and-j-rodriguez).

Comment: Una pregunta, has tenido en cuenta la barra de tareas de Windows? Eso sin más de 8 pixeles

Answer (score 0):

Redimensiona en la carga, Load, con el ancho que tienes (el de tu ventana) y alto el que te de el equipo.

```
<!-- language: c# -->
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.Location = new Point(0, 0); //sobra si tienes la posición en el diseño
   this.Size = new Size(this.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Size.Height);
}
```